# List out of index Error

Tags: python, django-orm

I have a for loop such as:

```
staff = Staff.objects.all().order_by('person__full_name')
for k in staff:
    categ = k.staff_job_categories.all()[1]
    if categ.name == unicode("xxx","utf-8"):
        t = categ.name
```

But for `categ = k.staff_job_categories.all()[1]`
I get an List out of index Error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you taking for granted that `k.staff_job_categories.all()` has at least 2 elements?

Comment: Thanks for -1 . staff_job_categories is ManyToManyField and has at least two elements in all database.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Anyway, your code implies that **every** `k` (instance of `Staff`) has at least two `staff_job_categories`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `print len(k.staff_job_categories.all())` will output `0` or `1` because there are no staff job categories for this item or just only one category exists (which has index `0` and not `1`).

So if you're interesting exactly in second category if it exists your code can be changed to

```
staff = Staff.objects.all().order_by('person__full_name')
for k in staff:
    categories = k.staff_job_categories.all()
    if len(categories) < 2:
        continue
    categ = categories[1]
    if categ.name == unicode("xxx","utf-8"):
        t = categ.name
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `k.staff_job_categories.all()` is either empty or has a single item.

You could test and try something along these lines.

```
all_categ = k.staff_job_categories.all()
if all_categ:
   categ = all_categ[0]
```